# How do I remove the month and year from the top of an Android CalendarView?

Tags: android, android-layout, calendar, calendarview

I currently have a CalendarView like so below:

[image]
<sub>(source: [gyazo.com](http://gyazo.com/8a9500376cf842d4e94d4c0545155a32.png))</sub>

There are a few things I want to change on this CalendarView. The first is that I don't want to display the month and year at the top of the calendar, is it possible to remove this? The next is to make the calendar not clickable, I've tried all of these and none seem to work:

```
android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
android:clickable="false"
```

The last change is that I'm unsure as to why the calendar has to be a fixed size, I would like it to be a lot smaller and by changing the layout_width and layout_height from "match_parent", this seems to cause all sorts of problems.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Ever find your answer?

Comment: @jcaruso Sorry I never found an answer to this. :( Please let me know if you ever do, I'd really like to know. I had to just workaround it in my app design instead.

Comment: 3 years and no answer to this? please let me know if you ever find one!